# How to create a javascript library that can be used in multiple projects?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

So I have a custom-made javascript library that I use in multiple projects. The problem is that if I make a change in one of the projects, then I have to into all the projects that use that library and replicate the changes. I want to be able to make the changes in the original library and all the projects that use/reference it are automatically updated. How do I go about doing this in Visual Studio (2013)?

Comment: make attempt bfore

Comment: Why not use a CDN? Upload the file you created into a CDN and make sure the link is consistent in all your projects.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Facade design pattern : (Function's name VS function's implementation )

You need to define **contract** (Called `interface` in JAVA) to avoid changing the name of functions .

Briefly, **Don't change name of functions, Change implementation's function** .

## 2. Attach your logic to non-changebale nameSpace :

```
var api={}; /*"api" is namespace*/
api.myFn=function(a,b){
    return a+b;
}
```

is Better than :

```
var myFn=function(a,b){
        return a+b;
    }
```

## 3. Use Anonymous function :

Best practices are to wrap the code of the WHOLE library with anonymous functions.

```
 (function(api){
       api.myFn=function(a,b){ /*"myFn" is attached to nameSpace*/
            return a+b;
       };
       window.myLibrary=api; /*Publish your library to be used outside of anonymous function */
 })({}) /*{} is the value of api*/
```

Then **in other files/other projects**, you  can use it like so : `myLibrary.myFn(4,5)`

## DEMO :

```js
     (function(api){
           api.myFn=function(a,b){ /*"myFn" is attached to nameSpace*/
                return a+b;
           };
           window.myLibrary=api; /*Publish your library to be used outside of anonymous function */
     })({}) /*{} is the value of api*/

     console.log(
         myLibrary.myFn(4,5)
       )
```